# App freezes several seconds before start on device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, startup, freeze

I'm a free developer and I use my swift application on my iPhone 7. I'm using Swift 3 and iOS 10. 
So the problem is, sometimes (like 2 of 10 times) when I start the app, iOS freezes like 5 seconds before my app actualy comes to the screen. In this time I only see the app icon is in the highlighted state. This only happens with my own app, not with other apps.

My app also does nothing special on startup and this only happens on the real device, the debugger in Xcode always starts immediately.

So is this a normal behavior? And does it work properly when I decide to put it on the App Store?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please click on the correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this happen to me before. No, this does not happen when it is put out on the App Store. One way to get around this is to use TestFlight. You can upload your archive to apple and select on the 'TestFlight' tab of your app. Click on internal testing and then click on your email and the version of the app you want to test. You should then get an email on your Apple ID telling you to test the app, and it will let you download it. Good question :)

Comment: Okay, thank you, then I will just hope for the best. I'm currently a free developer, but I will definelty use TestFlight if the time has come. :)

Answer (score 0):

To test the same version which would have been uploaded to the store quickly, change the build configuration to release. To do so, click on your app's name (top left), press edit schema, click the build configuration dropdown, also deselect debug executable. (make sure to turn it back when you're going to debug, or create a new schema with the above settings to let you switch quickly in the future)

You might also try using instruments, that lag on startup might happen if you're trying to load many things in memory on your initial view controller's `viewDidLoad` or app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` load, especially when trying to load big files such as images, videos or large plists. You might want to try using instruments (the time profiler instrument specifically) in order to check it out.